# Installing PCL for ROS Indigo

Tags: pcl, ros-indigo, cmake

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have installed the latest PCL on Ubuntu 14.04 ROS Indigo, using the website: http://pointclouds.org/downloads/linux.html

sudo add-apt-repository ppa:v-launchpad-jochen-sprickerhof-de/pcl

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install libpcl-all

Added to CMake:

find_package  (PCL REQUIRED)
...

include_directories(${PCL_INCLUDE_DIRS})
...

etc

But I get an error at find_package method saying that:

Could not find a package configuration file provided by "PCL" with any of
the following names:

```
PCLConfig.cmake
pcl-config.cmake
```

Add the installation prefix of "PCL" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set "PCL_DIR"
to a directory containing one of the above files.  If "PCL" provides a
separate development package or SDK, be sure it has been installed.

Meaning that PCL was not installed correctly. Now my question is that what did I miss during the course of installation or did I mistype something when finding packages?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/201516/installing-pcl-for-ros-indigo/) by [RosFan19](https://answers.ros.org/users/21450/rosfan19/) on ROS Answers with karma: 107 on 2015-01-22

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You do not need to install the PPA. Please [purge](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/ppa-purge.1.html) the PPA from your system.

To pull in PCL as a dependency for your source package automatically, modify your package.xml [like so](https://github.com/ros-perception/pcl_conversions/commit/a868e1a16e442c135f66a9738619d290bc4ee896)

Then go into the base of your workspace and run:

```
rosdep install --from-paths src --ignore-src --rosdistro indigo -y
```

Rosdep will install the correct version of everything. A good reference for how to add PCL to your CMakeLists is [here](http://wiki.ros.org/hydro/Migration#PCL)

---

Originally posted by [paulbovbel](https://answers.ros.org/users/3632/paulbovbel/) with karma: 4518 on 2015-01-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [simaopp](https://answers.ros.org/users/32526/simaopp/) on 2017-11-30**:
Can you please be more detailed about how to do it? I cant install it on ROS.
Thank you